# angular2 rxjs listen server with some intervals for set of requests simultaneously

Tags: angular, rxjs, polling, angular2-observables, subscriptions

Have such situation: need to listen server with some intervals for set of requests simultaneously. In other words, need to have a lot of instances of observables and subscribe for each of the instances. But how it implement with rxjs -- question for me.

Demonstrating part of the code(pseudocode) of it:

```
public publishNewPolling(pollingId, param2) {
    private polling = {};
    /*Object which contain corresponding
        parameters(pollingId, publishingTime and so on)*/
    private pollings: Array = []; /*array of polling-objects*/
    ....
    polling['pollingId'] = pollingId;
    polling['publishingTime'] = getPublishingTime(); /*get time of publishing*/
    polling['param2'] = param2;
    ....
    pollings.push(polling);
    this.listenServer(polling); /*that method can be called a lot of times for new instance of polling object. Creating new observable and subscribing for it*/
    private listenServer(polling) {
        let isFirstPublish: boolean = true;
        let timer: any = Observable.interval(1000).startWith(0)
            .flatMap(() => this.MyService.getStatus({
                param1: polling['pollingId'],
                param2: polling['param2']
            }))
            .subscribe((res) => {
                this.polling['result'] = res.Result; /*write result of request in prorerty of corresponding object each 1000ms*/
                if (isFirstPublish) {
                    this.MyService.publishNewPolling(this.polling); /*publish new polling-object and tracked it state in another component*/
                    isFirstPublish = false;
                }
                if (res.Result.Status === 'Finished' || res.Result.Status === 'Canceled') {
                    timer.unsubscribe();
                    this.deletePolling(polling['pollingId']);
                }
            });
    }

    private deletePolling(pollingId) {
        /*there we deleting corresponding polling from this.pollings */
    }
}
```

But this code works only for one *polling-object* in real application, because when we calling *listenServer-method* there are created new instance of observable which rewriting previous instances of it with new *polling-object*. But I need to have a lot of instances of observables(generated with *listenServer-method* and various *polling-objects*) and subscribe for each of the instances. In what way it would be better implement that situation ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Could you add more details about what's best result you want to achieve?

Comment: End result which I want to achieve: having a lot of requests to the server, polling server for each request with predetermined interval -- what is the way to implement it using RxJs ? Thank you.

Comment: are you looking for an centralized event bus and send you subscription id on each event fire?